# JOIN replaces the original id with the id of joined table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, join, model-view-controller

I got four tables

1. Links (id, user_id, link_data, category_id, submit_date)
2. Users (id, username, password, status)
3. Categories (id, name, slug)
4. Tags (id, link_id, tags)

I want to show all link details with username, Category name & slug and tags but with join it replaces the links.id with the category.id.

```
$catid = Category::where('slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail()->id;

$linksbycategories = DB::table('links')
->where('category_id', '=',$catid)
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'links.user_id')
->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'links.category_id')
->join('tags', 'tags.link_id', '=', 'links.id')->get();
return $linksbycategories;
//return view('category', ['linksbycategories' => $linksbycategories]);
```

I have 3 tags of link id 1 and the result I get is 3 times data of first link information with link id as 7 which is the category id of that link. How can I solve this.

Comment: Have you tried adding a ->select() in there to specify exactly what you want to gather from the query..

Comment: Yes @Petay87 I did but then it won't show any of the join data, I only get Links table data.

Comment: What if instead of using DB::table, you use the model so links::where

Comment: links::where has the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please add below code into link model:

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User','id','user_id');
}
public function Category()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Category','id','category_id');
}
public function Tags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tags ','link_id','id');
}
```

and also make changes into query as below:

```
$linksbycategories = App\Link::with('User','Category','Tags')
->whereHas('Category',function($q) use($slug){
$q->where('slug', '=', $slug);
})->get();
```

Comment: It worked, thanks @brinda-fadadu Can you also help me with pagination. How can I get the pagination in the blade view. {{$data->links()}} is not working.

Comment: You have to add `->paginate(15);` instead of `->get();`